# I have a dataframe with lists of dictionaries. Json_normalize and appending to a new df

Tags: python, json, pandas

This is what one row of `themesdf` looks like:

```
[{'code': '1', 'name': 'Economic management'},
 {'code': '6', 'name': 'Social protection and risk management'}]
```

I want to normalize each row and add it to a `newdf`. This is what I have right now:

```
import pandas as pd

themesdf = json_df['mjtheme_namecode']
newdf = pd.DataFrame()
%timeit() 
for row in themesdf:
    for item in row:
        newdf.append(json_normalize(item, 'name'))
newdf
```

After printing out `newdf`, it comes it with nothing. My ultimate goal with this data is to get the top ten major project themes (column `'name'`).

Comment: `newdf = newdf.append(json_normalize(item, 'name'))`  As the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) `.append()` returns a new object. So you need to update the dataframe.

Comment: **[Never call DataFrame.append or pd.concat inside a for-loop. It leads to quadratic copying.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489724/1422451)**

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked on something similar. My solution was to explode the list so each json has its own row. Then normalize with `pd.json_normalize()`. That creates a new df which needs to be rejoined with the original table.

Since you didn't provide any test data here's my best guess as to what works:

```
import pandas as pd

# explode list column
explodedDf = themesDf.explode('mjtheme_namecode')

# normalize that column into a new df
normalizedDf = pd.json_normalize(explodedDf['mjtheme_namecode'])

# (optional) you may want to drop the original column
themesDf = themesDf.drop('mjtheme_namecode', axis = 1)

# join on index (default) with original df
newDf = themesDf.join(normalizedDf)
```